# Split angular factory into multiple files

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular factory just like this:

```
myApp.factory('parse', [function () {
  var parse = {};
  parse.a = {};
  parse.a.x = function () { /* ..., call parse.b.x */ };
  parse.a.y = function () { /* ... */ };
  parse.b = {};
  parse.b.x = function () { /* ..., call parse.a.y */ };
  /* ... */
  return parse;
}]);
```

The file is growing larger and larger by adding more attributes to `parse`. (Currently about 2K lines) So maybe it is the time to split into multiple files.

One problem here is that these functions has some dependencies. Simply split `parse.a`, `parse.b`, ... into each file will just lead circular dependency.

How may I split this file to multiple ones?

I'd prefer:

- It is better to keep current interface (or some mirror modification)
- Group functions by file by semantic, not dependency (e.g. all `parse.a.*` in one file)
- Not too many files (one file for each function)

Comment: Well, if your functions are so tight to each other, split it would require you to redesign your factory to work in a modular approach. Like, create smaller components with smaller responsibilities. The way it is right now, you won't be able to split it without a ugly workaround. Also, what is your parser parsing? Does it follow a parse architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this depends on how you build your project - each/some build tool has its own ways to deal with such cases.

With just angular you can use $injector to avoid circular dependencies - thats not very cool in general, but let you do pretty whatever, i.e.:

```
myApp.factory('parseA', ['$injector', function ($injector) {
  var parseA = {};
  /* can not access parseB here*/
  parseA.x = function () { 
    /* can access parseB here */
    return $injector.get('parseB').x(); 
  };
  parseA.y = function () { /* ... */ };
  /* ... */
  return parse;
}]);

myApp.factory('parseB', ['$injector', function ($injector) {
  var parse = {};
  parse.b.x = function () { return $injector.get('parseA').y() };
  /* ... */
  return parse;
}]);
```

Comment: I guess in normal cases difference is neglibale.